# Exclude Product Categories from Woocommerce widget

Tags: woocommerce

We want to hide/exclude a few specific woocommerce category from the woocommerce shop as well as all pages.

So far we managed to achieve this using code I found on the internet.
The code bellow hide the correct category from the shop page but when we do a search using the woocommerve search, the category are not hidden in the result page.

```
    //Insert excluded category ids here
    $excludes = array(3380,3308);
    $includes = explode(",",$widget_args['include']);

    $includes = array_filter($includes, function($value) use ($excludes) {
      return !in_array($value, $excludes);
    });
    $widget_args["include"] = implode(",", $includes);
    return $widget_args;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_categories_widget_dropdown_args', 'exclude_woocommerce_widget_product_categories');
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_categories_widget_args', 'exclude_woocommerce_widget_product_categories');
```

The code bellow does hide the category from the search page but not from the shop page

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_categories_widget_dropdown_args', 'organicweb_exclude_widget_category');
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_categories_widget_args', 'organicweb_exclude_widget_category' );
function organicweb_exclude_widget_category( $args ) {
        $args['exclude'] = array('15', '3380', '3308' );    // Enter the id of the category you want to exclude in place of '30'
        return $args;
}
```

Could anyone please help me merge the 2 pieces of code together?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Both of the code snippets you posted only hide categories from the widget, it has no effect on hiding the category otherwise. Not 100% on what your goal is, two things seem likely to me:

If you want to [Exclude products from a particular category on the shop page](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/exclude-a-category-from-the-shop-page/) do it with below code (does not hide the category, if you selected to show them under Design > Customizer > WooCommerce > Product Catalogue in the backend) as seen in the WooCommerce docs.

```
/**
 * Exclude products from a particular category on the shop page
 */
function custom_pre_get_posts_query( $q ) {

    $tax_query = (array) $q->get( 'tax_query' );

    $tax_query[] = array(
           'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
           'field' => 'slug',
           'terms' => array( 'clothing' ), // Don't display products in the clothing category on the shop page.
           'operator' => 'NOT IN'
    );


    $q->set( 'tax_query', $tax_query );

}
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', 'custom_pre_get_posts_query' );
```

To actually hide the category itself, do the following as documented here [Hide a WooCommerce Category from Shop Page](https://www.tychesoftwares.com/hide-woocommerce-categories-shop/), which does not hide the products of this category.

```
/**
 * Show products only of selected category.
 */
function get_subcategory_terms( $terms, $taxonomies, $args ) {

    $new_terms  = array();
    $hide_category  = array( 126 ); // Ids of the category you don't want to display on the shop page

      // if a product category and on the shop page
    if ( in_array( 'product_cat', $taxonomies ) && !is_admin() && is_shop() ) {
        foreach ( $terms as $key => $term ) {
        if ( ! in_array( $term->term_id, $hide_category ) ) { 
            $new_terms[] = $term;
        }
        }
        $terms = $new_terms;
    }
  return $terms;
}
add_filter( 'get_terms', 'get_subcategory_terms', 10, 3 );
```